# Basic safe sessions in ASP .Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

First off, I am not using Forms Authentication.

I found a great tutorial that almost does what I want:
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/358434/Keep-me-signed-in-until-Loggged-out

The only problem is that it does not seem like a good idea. It stores the username in the cookie. That seems very bad.

How could I do something like this tutorial but in a safe way?

I essentially just want this basic flow:

```
if user logged in then show page
```

User can have the option of being logged in for the session (30 mins of inactivity) or until they choose to explicitly logout.

I have a feeling I will need a session table in my db for this, but I am not sure.

It doesn't have to be top of the line security since this is for an intranet, but I do still want it to be somewhat safe.

Thanks

Comment: "First off, I am not using Forms Authentication" - why not?

Comment: Also, you have yet to "accept" an answer on any of your previous 8 questions. You should look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is in your Login function, once you have verified them just add:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(theUserName, persistCookieBoolean);
```

Now you have an authentication cookie set. No encrypting or decrypting needed. Get the username like:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

And see if they are logged in:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

And now you can set authorization easily in the web.config too. Related post: [Manual Access control in ASP .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629346/manual-access-control-in-asp-net/14630156#14630156)

Comment: I cannot seem to access HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name. I tried in my page load but I get an error.

Comment: What does `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` return tho? [LogonUserIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.logonuseridentity.aspx) != [User.Identity.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt your data (username, etc) before storing in the cookie.

Read the cookie, decrypt the data & then validate.

Check this:

[Encrypting & Decrypting Data in .NET Applications](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/05/21/encrypting-data-in-net-applications.aspx)

[Encrypt/Decrypt string in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-decrypt-string-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sessions.

Example Code VB:

On login do:

```
Session("Username") = "username"
```

Then each time on page load check if `Session("Username")` has any data/is not null.

If it's null or empty then the Session has expired and you can kick them out of the page.