# Using cookies to auto-login a user in asp.net (custom login)

Tags: asp.net, security, cookies, authentication, persistent

i can't find on the net what i'm looking for so any help would be appreciated.
I have implemented a **custom login** form where the user enters his email and password to log in. I then query the database with those credentials (password is hashed and salted) and if both are found then i store the UserID in the Session state. If the user closes the browser then the Session is lost so he would have to log in again. 
I learned about using cookies to implement the "Remember me" functionality but i don't know what should i be storing in the cookie for the auto-login process and to make it secure.

PS: I know what a cookie is and how it works. I also know that storing the user credentials (email + password) in a cookie is NOT advised. **I'm using asp.net 4.0 with C#**

Actually i'm looking for the logic behind the auto-login system using cookies.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just use [FormsAuthentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to set the cookie:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(theUserID, true);
```

And then get it back:

```
string userId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

If you are worried about security, you can consider only using secure cookies (you will only be able to read that cookie over https).

There's more info on this in a related post: [Manual Access control in ASP .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629346/manual-access-control-in-asp-net/14630156#14630156)

**Update:** According to your comment, you don't think you can set a Forms Authentication cookie in your custom login form. So I created a blank ASP.NET 4 project, where I created a custom login -- it will log in any unauthenticated user. Here are the three pieces:

The `web.config` (your project should have something similar since you have a form on your site where people login):

```
<authentication mode="Forms"></authentication>
```

The code front:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="emptyWebApp._default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     Username: <asp:Label ID="_username" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace emptyWebApp
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                _username.Text = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                _username.Text = "Not logged in";
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("CookieMan", true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, you can set an Authentication cookie using `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` in your own custom authentication function, even one as irrational as this.

In this case, the first time they hit the page, it will show `Username: Not logged in` and then it will log them in as "CookieMan". Refreshing the page will show `Username: CookieMan`.

Comment: i'm using a **custom login** form so why are you suggesting me FormsAuthentication?

Comment: ...because it works? That will set a cookie to hold the currently logged in users' information. Try it. Although I would probably store the email instead of userId. I've used this on my own custom logins with custom role providers.

Comment: @osmiumbin added an example. Hopefully you'll play around with this and see it is a good and easy way to manage your auth cookie.

Comment: ok thanks, i'll try it but i'm confused, why is this better than the other way (using HttpCookie): http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31914/Beginner-s-Guide-To-ASP-NET-Cookies

Comment: @osmiumbin because the cookie it creates is recognized by the .NET framework and lets you use features like `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`, `<asp:LoginStatus`, etc, and various access control features (like easily securing files & pages to authenticated users only via a web.config entry).

Answer (score 1):

I have found very good articles about this problem. I recommend to read them all!

- http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/
- [Any gotchas I should be aware of regarding this approach to persistent logins ("Remember Me")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989778/any-gotchas-i-should-be-aware-of-regarding-this-approach-to-persistent-logins?rq=1)
- [Best way for hashing a "remember me" cookie token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502972/best-way-for-hashing-a-remember-me-cookie-token/8508213#8508213)
- [The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-forms-based-website-authentication)
- [What is the best way to implement "remember me" for a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244882/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-remember-me-for-a-website)
- http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've done this I just make up some random "SessionId" guid and use that value.

If your code you can keep a list sessionId/UserId pairs and expire them as necessary.